# Creating file in java

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

This may sound easy but I when debugging through this code it just stops debugging, can't work out if its throwing an exception or not.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Writer output = null;
File file = new File("write.txt");
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
for (int i = 0; i < audioDataDoubles.length; i++) {
    output.write(audioDataDoubles[i] + "\n");
}

output.close();
```

Comment: Stuck on the first line of code (Writer output = null)? Or stuck on the first line of the for loop?

Comment: It would be REALLY odd for it to hang on Writer output = null; maybe on the File.... = new File...?

Comment: Updated the question, I think its throwing an exception but cant see why

Comment: @Ben, please post the exception

Comment: It says FilNotFound Exception: /write.txt (Read-only file system)
do i change the writing permmissions under the folder? and if so, where exactly does it go by default?

Comment: you'll need to specify the full path of file, including the drive name. Try that and check

Comment: As you don't give a full path, it defaults to the current working directory. The message you quote pretty clearly says that you do not have authority to write in that directory. That would be your problem.

Comment: /C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/out.txt (No such file or directory) I now get this message, it does exist and i do have access, whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the case that you are creating a file at the location where you dont have the write access. Make sure if you have that.

Comment: I changed the string and now I get this message:
/C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/out.txt (No such file or directory)

There is a text file called out.txt on my desktop, any ideas?

Comment: Is it giving you out.txt, or write.txt ??

Comment: sorry, out.txt. I had an empty text file on my desktop that i used as a test.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using Android, debugging on my phone. I imagne its looking on my phone for storage